# Variables in __construct() when called by mysqli_fetch_object

Tags: php, object, mysqli, construct

I've got a class 'Event' which I am creating objects from via `mysqli_fetch_object`. The `__construct()` function is running and the objects variables are being set but they aren't set within the `__construct()` function.

I am using the following line to create the object:

```
$events[$x] = $result->fetch_object("Event")
```

When I run the following function by calling `$events[$x]->eventPlaces();` it echos the variable.

```
public function eventPlaces()
{
    echo $this->capacity;
}
```

However with the same code in the construct function it echos nothing.

```
public function __construct()
{
    echo $capacity;
    echo $this->capacity;
}
```

Apologies if I have explained this poorly, I've just got back into coding and OO php is new to me, if I missed anything then let me know.

Comment: is $this->capacity value being set before the constructor is called ?

Comment: Where do you set `$this->capacity`?

Comment: In truth I honestly don't know. I used to have it written inside the __construct() brackets and had $this->capacity = $capacity within the function; but then I realised that neither $this->capacity or $capacity had a value within the __construct() function. I removed them and somehow $capacity is still being set. I assume as there is a 'capacity' column in db it is setting the $capacity variable as part of fetch_object().

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php the properties are set before the object's constructor is called.

Comment: Thanks cbuckley knowing that is really useful. Need to start using the correct lingo in future !variables but properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your class to look like this:

```
class Event{
    protected $capacity;
    public __construct($capacity){
        $this->capacity = $capacity;
    }

    public function eventPlaces(){
        return $this->capacity;
    }
}
```

Then you would do this:

```
$events[$x] = $result->fetch_object("Event", array(12));
echo $events[$x]->eventPlaces();
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Everything you've put there makes sense; it was basically what I had originally and works fine if I create the object as you do here, but when I create the object via fetch_object() the __construct seems to behave differently.

Comment: you mean `mysqli_fetch_object()`?

Comment: Yes, I think, at least: $result->fetch_object("Event")

Comment: Is it possible that __construct() runs immediately, then the fetch_object function assigns values based on column names? That would explain why capacity isn't set in __construct() but is set straight afterwards?

Comment: I think what is happening, is you are not setting the capacity variable, you can pass it in as a parameter using an array like I did in my edits. `$events[$x] = $result->fetch_object("Event", array(12));` which should display `12` in my example